# enqueue jQuery into the footer

Tags: jquery, footer

I have looked but no where seems to cover how to place jQuery into the footer, at least not the way I have it in my theme, is there a way to place the following into the footer?

```
// Load jQuery
function my_register_jquery_function() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"), false, '1.7.1');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'cookie'
        , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.cookie.js'
        , array('jquery')
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'easing'
        , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js'
        , array('jquery')
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'nivo'
        , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js'
        , array('jquery')
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'setup'
        , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/setup.js'
        , array('jquery')
    );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_register_jquery_function');
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Set the fifth parameter of `wp_enqueue_script` or `wp_register_script` as `true`, and that script will be placed in the footer.

For example, your line

```
wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"), false, '1.7.1');
```

should be

```
wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"), false, '1.7.1', true);
```

And if you ever don't need/want to specify a version number, just set the fourth parameter to `false`.

More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

By the way, to make sure you're avoiding any conflicts, I would recommend you prefix the names of all your custom scripts.

Comment: Thanks, but, strange that didn't do anything?

Comment: "*Hmmm, strange that didn't do anything?*" - What actual code did you use?. Note also: de-registering a core script and registering a custom version **can and will** have unintended consequences.

Comment: I used `wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"), false, '1.7.1', true);`

Comment: "unintended consequences" that doesn't sound good is there a safe way of enqueuing the scripts?

Comment: "*is there a safe way of enqueuing the scripts?*" - Yes: **don't de-register core scripts in order to enqueue custom versions**. Just use the core-bundled, core-registered version.

Comment: Note also: `wp_enqueue_scripts` is too late in the execution process to *de-register* a registered script.

Comment: Re: "didn't do anything" -- check the page source. Is your version of jQuery being loaded at all? Is WP's version of jQuery still being loaded? As Chip said, try hooking `wp_deregister_script` to an earlier hook (maybe `wp_loaded`). Or, try changing the name of your script from `jquery` to `google-jquery` or something.